# why is the elements in HTMLCollection is different from what HTMLCollection.item() returned in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I apologize if the title makes you confused. Let me explain that.

In Chrome dev tool, if I use, for example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("login")
```

I get get an HTMLCollection which As you can see the 0-indexd property represents an typical [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object.

[image]

However, if I use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("login").item(0);
```

I got something like this:
[image]

As you can see this is not an element object. Instead, it is an [HTML Div element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)(correct me if I named it incorrectly).

My question is that why item() method does not return the same object in the HTMLCollection? To my understanding, HTMLCollection is an object, what is retrieved from item() method is a property of the object, so they are supposed to be the same. Why is the result is unexpected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the Chrome console formatting the object in a "pretty" way:

> By default, DOM elements are logged into the console as representation of their HTML

(From https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#formatting_dom_elements_as_javascript_objects)

If you want to view the actual object, you can obtain a JavaScript representation of it with:

```
console.dir(document.getElementsByClassName("login").item(0))
```

(You can optionally drop the `console.`)

See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference for info on the various console functions that are available.

Comment: Regarding of explanation: By default, DOM elements are logged into the console as representation of their HTML. what actually logged in the console is not a DOM element, is it? <div class="login">...</div> is a HTML element, am I right?

Comment: HTMLElement is a "subclass" of Element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement - So by way of polymorphism it's both ;)

Comment: thank you for writing the reply, but it still confuses me. The document said: DOM elements are logged into the console, but but after checking the HTMElement document,  <div class="login">...</div> is neither DOM element nor HTML element? is the document inaccurate?

Comment: It's an *HTML representation* of the element, as the document states. Chrome has formatted your object as it will appear in the HTML document itself. It's effectively the same information - the attribute values etc. will be the same in both representations.

Comment: This isn't accurate.